# Neo4j - full text search with AND operator

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database like this:
[image: Database]

I have also have a full text index created like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX translationRelationshipIndex IF NOT EXISTS
  FOR ()-[r:translation]-()
  ON EACH [r.text];
```

I get yellow and red nodes from this query:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships('translationRelationshipIndex', 'Yellow, Red') 
YIELD relationship  
WITH startNode(relationship) AS node
return node
```

I'd like to get all blue nodes which are connected with both nodes in any way. This query can return other kinds of nodes too so I'd like to use other nodes too.

I tried to find it using shortestPath but I can't do it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want ALL nodes directly related to each Yellow or Red node?

Comment: Hello, no, I would like to get all the blue nodes that have any connection to both the red and yellow nodes. For example, in the picture, the red node is connected directly to the blue one while the yellow one is connected via the pink one

Comment: But what _exactly_ does this mean?: "This query can return other kinds of nodes too so I'd like to use other nodes too." And what exactly do you mean by connected "in any way" (directly connected, via any length path, or ...)? Note: every node in your image is connected in some way to every other node.

Comment: via any length ;)

Comment: That could mean returning a large portion of the DB in the general case, and the entire DB in the worst case. Is your data organized such all possible paths are pretty short?